# When to use PDO prepared queries. mysql_real_escape error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm been making a php site, developing on my local machine. Really new to this so this is the first thing i've ever attempted. When I moved to my host, i get the following error:

```
 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied             for user 'matthew'@'localhost' (using password: NO)  on line 11
```

I've searched on here a fair bit and I'm pretty sure its because i need to 'prepare' my queries. What I am unsure of is when is it correct to prepare, and when not. I've added some of my queries below to explain in detail:

connection to db:

```
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=wmpt", $username, $password);
//echo "Connected to database"; // check for connection
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Here is an example query:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['run']);


$STH = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM tblusers WHERE username = '$username' ");
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
$result = $STH->fetch();
```

My question is, do I only need to "prepare" a query if I am querying/inserting/updating the DB with user submitted data?

Is the above query bad practice? What if it didnt contain user submitted data, ie i wanted to query

```
 $STH = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM tblusers WHERE username LIKE '%hotmail%' ");
```

That probably a bad example, but I'm illustrating a developer defined query.

Is this the reason I get, and how i can avoid:

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for     user 'matthew'@'localhost' (using password: NO)  on line 11
```

Answer (score 4):

To address the error you're receiving, [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) requires an open connection via `mysql_connect()`. Because you don't have one, it's attempting to connect and failing (using a username of `matthew`, whereas your PDO is connecting with `root`). Additionally, you cannot (or, *shouldn't*) mix and match `mysql_real_escape_string()` and `PDO` - they're different libraries.

Regarding "when" to use prepared statements, the general rule of thumb is whenever values are not hardcoded. Your example of `LIKE '%hotmail%'` doesn't need to be prepared, it's hardcoded and never going to change (unless you manually update it, of course).

If you have a query that will take in a variable of any sort, be-it data from `$_POST` or `$_GET`, or a variable that a developer made 10 lines before the query, you should use a prepared statement (or at least escape it, check out [PDO::quote](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)).

Comment: To be sure, you should escape *any* and *all* values substituted into your query. Even programmer-defined values can have unexpected issues.

Comment: @tadman Precisely; any variable that is not hardcoded should be escaped - either via a prepared statement or the very least an escaping-function.

Comment: thanks for the detail on best practices - really really helpful

Answer (score 4):

If you're using PDO, you should not be using `mysql_real_escape_string`. The PDO library has a very robust [SQL placeholder method](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) that does a much better job.

```
$STH = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM tblusers WHERE username = :username");
$STH->bindParam(':username', $username);
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
$result = $STH->fetch();
```

Comment: thanks loads, the list is also really appreciated - great guide